# Accessing dictionaries given django template's attributes?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So my problem is that I need to iterate over a dictionary given an attribute, which is the value of the for loop. For example, I have a dictionary called `my_dictionary` which is being iterated by a for loop in a django template, with an attribute called `q`. What I need is to access to that dictionary by using the `q` attribute. I tried with `{{my_dictionary.q}}`, `{{my_dictionary.{{q}} }}` but none of them did work. What can I do? I guess it should be similar as in Python `my_dictionary[q]`. Thank you.

Update: Actually, `q` has nothing to do with `my_dictionary`. Suppose that `q` is every element of a list `[1,2,3]` meanwhile `my_dictionary` is a dictionary with the following form: `{1: ['a','b','c'], 2:['a'], 3:['c']}`. So what I'm trying to do is access to each value of the dictionary given the values of the first list `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you return a dictionary from view to a template. Say your dictionary name is `my_dictionary` then in a template you need to do like this:

```
{% for q in my_dictionary %}
    <p> {{ q.your_dictionary_key_name }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

for iterating over list items in a dictionary

```
{% for key, value in dictionary.items %}
    <li><a href="{{key}}">{{value}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Actually, `q`has nothing to do with `my_dictionary`. Suppose that `q`is every element of a list `[1,2,3]` meanwhile `my_dictionary` is a dictionary with the following form: `{1: ['a','b','c'], 2:['a'], 3:['c']}`. So what I'm trying to do is access to each value of the dictionary given the values of the first list `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom template filter:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
register = Library()
...
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    # use .get so that if the key does not exist a KeyError will be raised
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

usage in templates:

```
{% for q, value in my_dictionary.items %}
    {{ my_dictionary.items|get_item:<key_variable_here> }}
{% endfor %}
```